# Unknown MySQL server host on Jenkins docker

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkinsfile stage I'd like to build the project, but it throws error when trying to get mysql working. The error thrown when running jenkins is: `Unknown MySQL server host 'web_db'` (this is related to the line below:

```
sh '''mysql -u root -h web_db --password=root database -e \'SELECT 1\' > /dev/null'''
```

that is contained here in this Jenkinsfile (just the stage)

```
stage('Configure web...') {
    agent {
        docker {
            label 'web'
            image ECR_URL_WEB
            args "-v${env.HOST_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY}_${env.BRANCH_NAME}:/projectname"
            reuseNode true
        }
    }
    steps {
        sh '''
            if [ ! -f ./web/.htaccess ]; then
            cp /config/domainname.htaccess ./web/.htaccess
            fi
        '''
        sh '''
            if [ ! -f ./app/config/parameters.yml ]; then
            cp /config/parameters.yml ./app/config/
            fi
        '''
        sh '''
            if [ ! -d ./vendor ]; then
            php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-progress
            fi
        '''
        script {
            try {
                sh '''mysql -u root -h web_db --password=root database -e \'SELECT 1\' > /dev/null'''
            } catch (err) {
                sh '''
                    bin/console doctrine:database:create
                    bin/console doctrine:schema:create
                '''
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  jenkins-home:

services:
  jenkins:
    image: localhost:5000/jenkins-docker
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    container_name: jenkins-docker
    networks:
      - net

  db_host:
    container_name: web_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

Comment: replace 'web_db' with 'db_host'

Comment: You should put that as an answer @SameerK

Answer (score 1):

The containers needs to be referred by their `service names` and not by actual `container names`. In your case, the the service name for `web_db` container is `db_host`, so replace `web_db` with `db_host`.